# Problema con JXTable swingx evento mouseClicked

Tags: java, java-swing

Esto peleando con una tabla (JXTable) para que me diga la celda seleccionada con el ratón. Eso lo tengo más o menos solucionado. Lo que ocurre es que cuando selecciono uno fila de la tabla y luego hago clic sobre una zona de la tabla en la que no hay registros me sigue apareciendo el contenido de la última celda seleccionada.

Si por el contrario, antes de seleccionar ninguna fila de la tabla hago clic sobre la zona en la que no hay registros salta un error "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index", normal por otra parte.

Lo que quiero es saber en qué zona de la tabla hago clic, para saber cómo proceder, pero no sé muy bien cómo detectar esa zona.

```
tabla.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        int fila = ((JXTable) e.getSource()).getSelectedRow();
        int col = ((JXTable) e.getSource()).getSelectedColumn();
        System.out.println(
                tabla.getModel()
                        .getValueAt(tabla.getRowSorter()
                                .convertRowIndexToModel(fila), 
                                tabla.convertColumnIndexToModel(col)));
    }
});
```

tabla es como digo un JXTable, y esto es lo que tengo para recoger los eventos del ratón dentro de ella. Decir que la tabla puede ordenarse, filtrarse, recolocarse etc., por eso tengo convertRowIndexToModel y convertColumnIndexToModel

Alguien me puede orientar un poco por favor.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Para aquell@s que estén en la misma situación que yo les dejo la solución que he encontrado. Espero que pueda servirles:

```
tabla.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        int fila = tabla.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint());
        int col = tabla.columnAtPoint(e.getPoint());
        try {
            System.out.println(
                    tabla.getModel()
                            .getValueAt(tabla.getRowSorter()
                                    .convertRowIndexToModel(fila),
                                    tabla.convertColumnIndexToModel(col)));
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException aioobe) {
            System.out.println("No hay nada seleccionado.");
        }
    }
});
```

:)